# Web Services under a web application directory

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-config

I have a web application, regular asp.mvc. Within the folder, I have 2 folders for web services - one is intended for testing. We want the test service under the web application so we only have to bother getting one URL registered/paid for.

I got an error on trying to access the web service however. It appears that the web.config for the service (which uses Web API and EF6) will be invalid when it contains a connection string entry which does not match the web.config of the web application. So the web.config for the web app (in some root folder, WebApp let's say), has connection string for DB1. The service has a web.config (in WebApp/WebServiceTest), which has the same connection string name, but a database name of DBTest. That causes the error:

> Parser Error Message: The entry 'Entities' has already been added.

There is no DI in order to inject the entities into the app so that I could rename the connection string entry in the web service. We may be able to go that route and change the library that interacts with DB, but are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the inheritInChildApplications setting. Using that in the root web.config will solve our problem.